# How do I convert between two different 2D coordinate systems?

Tags: 2d, coordinates

I'm trying to convert a coordinate from one coordinate system to another, so that I can draw it on an image.

Basically the destination coordinate system is as follows:

```
X range: 0 to 1066
Y range: 0 to 1600
```

(just a standard image I'm drawing onto with the size of 1066 x 1600)

The position I'm trying to draw onto the image actually has the exact same size, but the coordinate system is different.  The span all of the coordinates is 1066x1600.

But a coordinate example would be:

```
(111.33f, 1408.41f)
(-212.87f, 1225.16f)
```

The range of this coordinate system is:

```
X range: -533.333 to 533.333
Y range: 533.333 to 2133.333
```

I feel like this is VERY simple math, but for some reason I'm not getting it.

How can I convert the coordinates provided into the first coordinate system?

Comment: If the two coordinate systems have the same base vectors you can simply use a scaling factor. If they don't have the same base vectors a [base change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You can normalize the first value, this will give you a value in the [0,1] range. You can think of that as X percentage, the percentage the value maps to between the minimum and maximum values. Then you can find where that percentage belongs in your destination coordinate system by seeing what value is X percentage through the destination system. I'll use Java code as an example language, I'm sure the concepts are clear enough to translate to any language though.

So normalize:

```
public static float normalize(float value, float min, float max) {
    return Math.abs((value - min) / (max - min));
}
```

Using your example you'd input:

```
xPercent = normalize(x,0,1066);
```

Then find where it lays in the destination system. With something like

```
destX = xPercent*(Math.abs(max-min)) + min;
```

Or to use your values:

```
destX = xPercent*(Math.abs(533.33--533.33)) + -533.33;
```

So for example with an x value of 1000 you'd map that to your destination coordinate system to `467.29`.

**Alternatively**, if the coordinate systems will always be the same, you can pre-compute the ratio between them.

So:

```
xRatio = (Math.abs(srcMax-srcMin))/(Math.abs(destMax-destMin));

destX = x*xRatio+destMin;
```

Comment: Why Java(C#)? He didn't ask for Java code :)

Comment: It's to give an example. It doesn't need to be used as is, and the concept is clear enough.

Comment: But if I do this: destX = xPercent*(Math.abs(533.33--533.33)) + -533.33;  I always get a negative value, and the result coordinate system is just from 0-1066, should i switch all the coordinates around?

Comment: Switched them around and I'm still getting http://dump.tanaris4.com/sota.png just like in another post, maybe I'm having another issue altogether (related to C# and drawing).  Thanks guys!

Comment: Got it, for some reason I had to do xPercent = 1.0f - xPercent

Comment: Sounds like it's backwards or flipped somewhere. Glad it worked though!

Answer (score 4):

It is simple math:

```
res = ( src - src_min ) / ( src_max - src_min ) * ( res_max - res_min ) + res_min
```

src - source coordinate system

res - result coordination system

**Edit - explanation of math**

`( src - src_min ) / ( src_max - src_min )` translates it to coordinate system starting at zero with equal length of source coordinate system `(0.0, src_max - src_min )`. Then it scales value to coordinate system `(0.0, 1.0)`.

`* ( res_max - res_min )` this scales value to coordinate system starting at zero with length of result coordination system `(0.0, dst_max - dst_min)`

`+ res_min` translates value to result coordinate system `(dst_min, dst_max)`

Comment: I thought this as well, but it's not displaying properly: http://dump.tanaris4.com/sota.png  The final coordinate should hit where the white circle is at the bottom

Comment: This doesn't explain them math at all, why not? :)

Comment: @Byte56 For me is formula enough to understand something especially if it uses only arithmetic operations, but I've added explanation for people that would need it :)

Comment: @Geesu Then your are probably doing something else bad (rendering matrices? ).

Comment: Thanks for updating that. I generally think it's better to give an answer that tries to explain the why. Otherwise you're just giving the answer to this question, instead of how to solve this question *and* similar problems. It's a "give a man a fish, teach a man to fish" type thing.

Answer (score 3):

The basic equation for 2D coordinate tranformation (in algebra, without rotation involved) is:

```
TargetCoordinate = TranslateFactor + ScalingFactor*SourceCoordinate
```

given two points in TargetCoordinate (T1, T2) that corresponds to two points in SourceCoordinate(S1, S2), `TranslateFactor` and `ScalingFactor` is given by solving :

```
T1 = TranslateFactor + ScalingFactor*S1
T2 = TranslateFactor + ScalingFactor*S2
```

which result :

```
TranslateFactor = (T2*S1 - T1*S2) / (S1 - S2)
ScalingFactor   = (T2 - T1) / (S2 - S1)
```

In your case, for the x coordinate

```
S1 = 0    -> T1 = -533.333
S2 = 1066 -> T2 = 53.333
```

And thus,

```
TranslateFactor = -533.333
ScalingFactor   = 1.000625
=> TargetCoordinate = (-533.333) + (1.000625)*SourceCoordinate
```

y coordinate follow the same procedure

Comment: S1 and S2 cannot have the same x/y coordinate which leads to a division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions:

- You are (eventually) interested in a matrix impementation, for convenience and power; and
- You are familiar with homogeneous coordinates.

Then the question migrates to: What is the homgeneous transformation matrix for my basis change?

To answer this we need the answers to three subsidiary quesions first:

1. Where did my origin move to?
2. What happened to my X-axis? Let (M11,M12) be the coordinates of the
   point
3. What happened to my Y-axis?

Define the answers to these thre questions to be as follows:

1. (M31,M32) are the coordinates of the new origin under the original coordinate system.
2. (M11,M12) are the coordinates of the new unit x-vector in the original coordinate system.
3. (M21,M22) are the coordinates of the new unit y-vector in the original coordinate system.

Then the homogenous transformation matrix is:

```
( M11, M12,  0 )
( M21, M22,  0 )
( M31, M32,  1 )
```

My convention here is that points are represented by row vectors, which is the normal computer graphics convention; the mathematicians and physicists often use the oppsoite.

Comment: A coordinate system can be described by such a matrix : M11 = Xaxis.X, M12 = Xaxis.Y, M21 = Yaxis.X, M22 = Yaxis.Y, M31 = origin.X, M32 = origin.Y. Given a coordinate system matrix A and a coordinate system matrix B, P * A * Inverse(B), where P is the representation of a point as  coordinates in A, yields the representation of the point as coordinates in B.